# MS Access after insert event

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables in access, A and B, both with a case ID field and several other fields. I am trying to set up a process where if I insert a record in A with a new case ID, only the case ID of that record inserted in table A gets populated in table B.

I have tried using an After Insert event macro of table A with a create a record into table B action which should create a record with the case ID in table B. This work fine if none of the fields apart from the Case ID in table B are required. However, if I have other fields that are required in Table B, the create a record into table B does not happen upon insert into Table A.

How do I fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a `Command Button` to insert same `Case ID` to both table using `SQL` statement. But you must give data for required field.

Comment: Why would a record be record in table B just because a record was created in table A?

Comment: Welcome to SO. *if I have other fields that are required in Table B, the create a record into table B does not happen* That's the answer. If some fields of Table B has been set to require data when a new record is inserted, the only way to avoid that is feeding those fields with data OR change the table setup and make those fields non-required.